# Finding the height of a triangle without using trigonometry functions

Tags: triangles, pythagorean-triples

```
             A
            /|\
           / | \
          /  |  \
         /   |   \
        c    h    b 
       /     |     \
      /      |      \
  B  /___a1__|___a2__\ C
```

Given a triangle ABC as shown above.
By using the Pythagoras theorem, a1= { c^2-b^2+(a1+a2)^2 } / 2(a1+a2) .
How can I express h using a1+a2, b, and c?

Comment: are a1,a2,b and c given constants?

Comment: The straightforward approach would be $\quad h=\sqrt{c^2-a1^2}=\sqrt{b^2-a2^2}.\quad$

Comment: the only given constants are a, b, and c. a1 and a2 are not given.

Comment: also, a=a1+a2..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula)(It has algebraic proof using the Pythagorean theorem), we have
$$
S = \sqrt{p(p-(a_1+a_2))(p-b)(p-c)}, \text{ where } p = \dfrac{a_1+a_2+b+c}{2}. 
$$
Also,
$$
S = \dfrac{1}{2} (a_1+a_2)\times h
$$
Can you proceed from here?

---

$$
\dfrac{1}{2} a\times h = \sqrt{p(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)}\\
\dfrac{1}{4}a^2 h^2= p(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)\\
h^2=4p(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)/a^2
$$

Comment: if a=a1+a2, then h^2=  (a+b+c)(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c) / 4c^2

Comment: is this right??

Comment: I think that should be $ h^2= 4(a+b+c)(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c) / \color{blue}{a}^2$

Comment: why isn't 4 in the denominator?

Comment: See the edit. Is it clear now?

Comment: Thanks a lot ～～